# Python MySQL Connector executemany with Extra Values

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

Is there a built-in way to ignore fields in a dictionary when using MySQL's `executemany()` to insert data?

I need to insert data from a relatively large dataset given to me in JSON files.  The basic layout of the JSON data is thus:

```
{
    "data" : [
        { "f1" : 42, "f2" : "abc", "f99" : "useless stuff" },
        { "f1" : 43, "f2" : "def", "f99" : [ "junk", "here" ] },
        { "f1" : 44, "f2" : "ghi", "f99" : { "thing" : 99 } }
    ]
}
```

I have an insertion setup that looks like this:

```
import json
import mysql.connector
with open( 'huge_data_dump.json', 'rb' ) as fh:
    data = json.load( fh )
connection = mysql.connector.connect( **mysql_config )
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = 'INSERT INTO `example` ( `f1`, `f2` ) VALUES ( %(f1)s, %(f2)s )'
cursor.executemany( query, data[ 'data' ] )
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

The target table would look something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `example` ( `f1` INT, `f2` VARCHAR( 10 ) )
```

However, when I run this, I get an error:

```
Failed processing pyformat-parameters; Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

If I limit the import to only the first row in the example dataset, the insertion works perfectly:

```
cursor.executemany( query, data[ 'data' ][ : 1 ] )
```

The problem is coming from the extraneous data in the `f99` field that comes to me containing who-knows-what.  Which is fine for *me*: I don't want any information from `f99`.  However, the MySQL connector appears to want to convert the entire record's dictionary to safe strings before examining the query to see if the value is even needed.

I tried using a generator function to filter the dataset into the call to `executemany()`, but the connector complains about only being able to accept tuples and lists (which I feel is a rather un-Pythonic interface).

My last resort is to copy the data into a new dictionary, and filter out the unwanted fields before passing the data to `executemany()`.  However, these datasets are already large enough where I'm considering streaming them from the JSON source files in groups of a few hundred insertions at a time.  Additional loops trying to eliminate all the unwanted data is going to be a waste, and more code to maintain.  I'm sincerely hoping I'm overlooking something that the documentation doesn't cover, or glosses over.

I suppose I can start investigating some custom JSON filtering on the input, but, again, I'm hoping there's a simple, built-in approach to solving (what seems to be) a relatively common use case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator that creates a tuple of your needed columns for every record in your data list:

```
(d["f1"], d["f2"] for d in data['data'])
```

passing this generator to the executemany-function should work as expected.

EDIT: You may need to change the query into

```
query = 'INSERT INTO `example` ( `f1`, `f2` ) VALUES ( %s, %s )'
```

but i'm not really sure about that.

Comment: Good thought, but the inline generator fails the same way a function generator does.  The connector is doing too much type checking to allow this to work.  I can use list comprehension, but it appears as if the entire list is iterated before being passed to the `executemany()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Dear people from the future:

After fighting this for a little while, I decided to attack the problem from the input side.

The built-in JSON implementation doesn't *exactly* support streaming, but you can specify custom decoding of various parts of the JSON data as it is loaded into the interpreter's memory.  Abusing my power of being able to intercept all object-to-dictionary decoding, I decided to go ahead and manipulate the incoming data there.

Also of note: The MySQL connector has some limits on the amount of data being passed in one transaction, so I went ahead and cached a couple hundred of these "converted" dictionaries in my decoder, and insert them into the database as the file was being read by the JSON `load()` function.

#### In a nutshell:

```
import json

class CustomDecoder( json.JSONDecoder ):

    allowed = [ 'f1', 'f1' ]

    def __init__( self, **kwargs ):
        kwargs[ 'object_hook' ] = self.object_to_dict
        super( CustomDecoder, self ).__init__( **kwargs )
        self.cache = []

    def object_to_dict( self, data ):

        # this check just identifies the object we need to insert
        if 'f1' in data:

            # permit allowed fields from the incoming dictionary
            data = dict(
                ( k, v )
                for k, v in data.iteritems()
                if k in self.allowed
            )

            # add data to batch cache
            self.cache.append( data )

            # check cache status
            if len( self.cache ) >= 200:

                # insert the cached records as a group for performance
                ### cursor.executemany( query, self.cache )

                # dump the cache
                self.cache = []

        # return modified data or pass through un-modified data
        return data

# connect to database, grab a cursor to it, set up the query

with open( 'import_file.json', 'rb' ) as fh:
    data = json.load( fh, cls = CustomDecoder )

# at this point, everything but left-overs in the cache should be inserted
```

#### Caveats:

1. You still need to insert any left-overs that are in the cache once the parser has finished loading the data.  I ended up maintaining the cache outside the CustomDecoder instance, so I could flush it once the internally-created CustomDecoder disappears.
2. Managing the query and cursor object requires a little more code to keep the interfaces relatively clean.  I decided to create a callback handler that's assigned to a class property.  The callback handler happens to know how to find the current cursor and query.